# Eloquent update() failing due to updated_at table ambiguity

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

Ok, this question stems from a Laravel 4.1.23 install.  I'm attempting to update multiple records using the Eloquent update() method on a query that includes a join:

```
ChildSchoolYear::whereNull('exit_date')->
join('school_years', 'child_school_years.school_year_id','=','school_years.id')->
update(array('child_school_years.exit_date'=>'`school_years`.`end_date`',
'child_school_years.editor_id'=>$userId))
```

Laravel is generating the correct SQL for the query content I'm providing above, but the full SQL statement generated is

```
update `child_school_years` 
inner join `school_years` on `child_school_years`.`school_year_id` = `school_years`.`id` 
set `child_school_years`.`exit_date` = `school_years`.`end_date`,
`child_school_years`.`editor_id` = 2, 
`updated_at` = 2014-08-15 02:00:33 where `exit_date` is null)
```

This would work except that the automatically added `updated_at` field exists in both the child_school_years and school_years tables, so the addition of the field by Laravel triggers the Exception `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous`.

Any suggestions on how to domesticate the updated_at piece?  I'd be happy to have the field updated, but I'll live without it if necessary should it be possible to eliminate it.

Comment: one workaround is to use the query builder instead of eloquent. Please refer to the below link http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9680

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to alter Eloquent behaviour, even adjusting `UPDATED_AT` column won't help, so you need to use either simple `Query\Builder`, like already suggested, or one of the methods below, that I find a bit better:

```
// easiest way
ChildSchoolYear::whereNull('exit_date')
  ->join('school_years', 'child_school_years.school_year_id','=','school_years.id')
  ->getQuery()  // get underlying base Query\Builder
  ->update(
    array(
      'child_school_years.exit_date'  => '`school_years`.`end_date`',
      'child_school_years.editor_id'  => $userId,
      'child_school_years.updated_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    )
  );

// also would work, temporary turn off auto timestamps
with($model = new ChildSchoolYear)->timestamps = false;

// above is the same as:
// $model = new ChildSchoolYear;
// $model->timestamps = false;

$model->whereNull('exit_date')
  ->join('school_years', 'child_school_years.school_year_id','=','school_years.id')
  ->update(
    array(
      'child_school_years.exit_date'  => '`school_years`.`end_date`',
      'child_school_years.editor_id'  => $userId,
      'child_school_years.updated_at' => Carbon\Carbon::now(),
    )
  );
```

Comment: Where is that getQuery() statement from?  I can't find it defined anywhere.  Both approaches look promising, but I'd prefer to use getQuery() if I can get more info on it.

Comment: Actually, I'm also interested in where the with() function is defined.  I can't seem to find either in the Laravel.com online docs.

Comment: Check the source, it's the best way to learn the framework. It is pretty well documented too. `getQuery` here is `Eloquent\Builder`s method, and `with` is just a tiny helper defined in `Illuminate\Support\helpers.php` - last one in the helpers docs: http://laravel.com/docs/helpers

Comment: Thanks for the reference.  I guess I've been spoiled by the PHP documentation, which generally explains the basics of every function - wading through the Laravel source lets you figure things out, but so far I've rarely found that it actually explains much directly.  I've also found it surprisingly difficult at times to navigate the source online.  Still, the advice remains useful.  Thanks.

Comment: No, not the online source. Get the code you have in your app. Online API docs are pretty much useless if you want to learn how things work.