# updated_at column ambigious while updating with eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5, ambiguous

I have 3 table cart,pharmacy and cart_pharmacies

**cart table**

```
cart_id | user_id | total_price | status | created_at | updated_at
```

**pharmacy table**

```
pharmacy_id | name | address_id | created_at | updated_at
```

**cart_pharmacies table**

```
cart_pharmacies_id | cart_id | pharmacy_id | created_at | updated_at
```

In cart modal i define relation

```
   public function pharmacy()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Pharmacy','cart_pharmacies','cart_id','pharmacy_id');
    }
```

In parmacy modal i define

```
public function cart()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart','cart_pharmacies','pharmacy_id','cart_id');
}
```

In controller i have pharmacy_id i am trying to update cart status with code

```
$pharmacy_id=$request->input('pharmacy_id');
$pharmacy=  Pharmacy::findOrFail($pharmacy_id);
$pharmacy->cart()->update(['status'=>1]);
```

but it is giving me error

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 
'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: update `cart` inner join 
`cart_pharmacies` on `cart`.`cart_id` = `cart_pharmacies`.`cart_id` set 
`status` = 1, 
`updated_at` = 2016-05-31 07:14:47 where `cart_pharmacies`.`pharmacy_id` = 5)
```

Comment: How are you passing updated_at value?

Comment: you can see on my code i am not passing updated_at values

Comment: That is the problem you are missing the single quotes around the updated_at value. There seems to be some common code which is passing the value. Have a look at it.

Comment: Not this is not a problem the problem is botth table cart_pharmacies and cart have updated_at column it cause ambiguous. i don't know how to solve that problem

Comment: If you feel this is not the issue, just try running the output sql you added i.e.  (update `cart` inner join 
`cart_pharmacies` on `cart`.`cart_id` = `cart_pharmacies`.`cart_id` set 
`status` = 1, 
`updated_at` = 2016-05-31 07:14:47 where `cart_pharmacies`.`pharmacy_id` = 5 ) in your phpmyadmin or any sql ui, you would get same error.

Comment: Actually the quote thing is handle by default in laravel. We have nothing to do with that. And even if i consider that its the problem with the quotes then the error will be different than this one. It will be a syntax error not about the ambigious. I am more concerned about how to handle the alias in the elequoent than handling the quotes as this can be done by laravel because thats the framework thing.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but maybe duplicated of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25320335/eloquent-update-failing-due-to-updated-at-table-ambiguity/25325707), and there is an useful answer to this question:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25325707/2116875

Comment: @chandresh_cool Did you understand that those queries are composed by Eloquent?

Answer (score 2):

SQL query error says there is multiple columns named 'updated_at' (both main and related tables) and cant decide which to update. It is a bug and I think there is no way to solve with eloquent as updated_at will be added at the end automatically without the table name specified.

Comment: I am inclined to agree

Answer (score 2):

```
$pharmacy->cart()->toBase()->update(['status'=>1, 'cart.updated_at' => now()]);
```

Use **toBase()** method and add **'cart.updated_at' => now()** to update data

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hope it helps others.

Comment: Wow !! Works like a charm. In my case the update query had an inner join and both had `updated_at` .

Answer (score 0):

Your are using timestamps in your pivot table which could be automatically controlled by Eloquent with withTimestamps() method.

In your parmacy modal:

public function cart()
{

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart','cart_pharmacies','pharmacy_id','cart_id')->withTimestamps();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found so far is the following:

Given that you have an array of values to update (`$values`) and your query (`$query`), you simply create a base query and add your columns manually:

```
$now = now();

// Manually add the timestamp columns
$values = $values + [
    'table.' . Model::CREATED_AT => $now,
    'table.' . Model::UPDATED_AT => $now,
];

$query->toBase()->update($values);
```

`Model` is an import of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, `table` is the name of the table you really want to update.

Not the best but it works, maybe this will become a feature in the future…

Answer (score 0):

Here is Link to overcome the issue

```
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/13909
```

The use of `toBase()` before updating assist me so much to solve the issue
happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

If you use modal please update your modal with this line

`public $timestamps = false;`

try, it may be helpful

Comment: i have done this it works but it does not store updated_at value

Comment: set your TIMESTAMP default value by CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in your database